# How to advertise in a mobile app made with Marmalade?

Tags: marmalade, ads

So I'm creating an app using Marmalade 6.3.2 SDK and I'm still wondering how to correctly integrate ads (banners **and** interstitial ads) into my app.

I'm currently using a webview to display both banners and interstitial ads but it slows down the app and it's a bit tricky.

I did not find any **up to date** Marmalade extensions available for both iOS and Android for any ad network (except for PlayHaven, but I'm not interested in that kind of advertisement). And extension are not available for BlackBerry nor Windows Phone anyway.

Does anyone have a better, cross-platform, up to date solution please ?

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 2):

There are many options available for ads in [marmalade's github site](http://www.github.com/marmalade). If you need some other custom solution, you can always use EDK to make your own extension/plugin.

WRT ads in BB10 and WP8, there's no EDK support for these platforms. EDK is available to Android and iOS only till the latest available version (6.3.2). There're plan to include BB10 and WP8 EDK in next major release, which is in beta (Marmalade 7) and should be announced in the next quarter. Which means you can't have native ad SDK in BB10 or WP8.

Till then you can use IwGameAds which shows HTTP/RESTful ads. Keep in mind that to enable clicking in the ad you'll need a workaround, available in marmalade's workaround section.

Comment: In case you don't have enough experience to make extensions using EDK, you can always hire someone to do it for you. (I offer the EDK services for cheap prices, in case you're interested).

Comment: EDK is now also available for WP8.

I ended using Revmob, Flurry and AdBuddiz extensions for advertisement.
But it is hard to find a good one that is maintained over time and SDK upgrades.